# SBT task executed twice

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to create a custom SBT task. My problem is that the task is executed twice and the output of the tasks are interleaved, which suggests parallel execution. This is a minified example of the task I am creating:

`theproject/project/ModuleTemplate.scala`:

```
object ModuleTemplate extends Build {
  lazy val createModule = inputKey[Unit]("Create a new module")
  override def settings = super.settings ++ Seq(
    createModule := {
      println("creating module...")
      println("interleaved")
    }
  )
}
```

The output of executing this task in the sbt console (`play createModule`):

```
creating module bla...
interleaved
creating module bla...
interleaved
```

Any idea what is causing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't it be `configKey` instead `inputeKey`?

Comment: @ayvango An inputKey defines a task that can accept input parameters: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html

Comment: Yes, I know, but I found no request for user input in the example

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was something wrong with either project files from IntelliJ or SBT files messing with the task execution. Anyways, I deleted all files that were generated by SBT and IntelliJ and the problem is solved.